# Conditional Operator: How much flexibility?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I would like to perform the following:

```
if(x == true)
{
    // do this on behalf of x
    // do this on behalf of x
    // do this on behalf of x
}
```

Using a conditional operator, is this correct?

```
x == true ? { /*do a*/, /*do b*/, /*do c*/ } : y == true ? ... ;
```

Is this malformed?

I am not nesting more than one level with a conditional operator.

The expressions I intend to use are highly terse and simple making a conditional operator, in my opinion, worth using.

P.S. I am not asking A. Which I should use? B. Which is better C. Which is more appropriate

P.S. I am asking how to convert an if-else statement to a ternary conditional operator.

Any advice given on this question regarding coding standards etc. are simply undesired.

Comment: This is mostly a style issue (although in some cases, you may find syntax gets in the way too). I'd say the first alternative is generally much more readable.

Comment: `if (a) b else c;` is a statement. `a ? b : c` is an expression. Pick the one that makes sense.

Comment: I don't think this woks... It throws an error for me....

Comment: What is your motivation behind this change? You've seen that too many people understand your code when they read it and you want to prevent that?

Comment: @DanielDaranas `/*da a*/` is represented by a very terse expression such as B(121, Y(36)).  Where I work they use highly terse expressions whereby `B and Y` are functions.  Considering such terse expressions, I though using a conditional operator would be suitable.

Comment: @Mushy: I don't see any reason to "compress" code more than necessary. Why would that be better?

Comment: Once upon a time, [when you had 12k RAM and a 10 cps printing terminal](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/ken-and-den.jpg), being terse was good. That went away about 1978.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I have no control over that.  Working with software that began in DOS where memory footprint mattered.

Comment: @Mushy: So, you are asking which is better, but you can't change it, because the code is really old. Sorry, but if you don't want to know which is better, because you can't change it, why are you asking? I still think that if you are ever writing NEW code, you should try as best as you can, to convert it to "more readable". There is no excuse these days to write unreadable code just because it's shorter.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Writing new code changes but there is a coding standard that has its' roots in the code that started in DOS.  I need to stay within that standard and code within that standard.  Thus, highly terse programming is necessary and I, as well as my former mentor, agree that ternary operator helps encapsulate changes in a single line.  I do not think it difficult to read so long as at most one level of nesting occurs.

Comment: @Mushy If you're so fond of your style, why were you asking?

Comment: @DanielDaranas I never asked a question, particularly this one, in which I want to know which style I should: A. Use  B. Prefer  C. What's better?  No, if your read the question (have you?) I am inquiring as how to write a ternary conditional statement formatted similar to an if-else.  Anything more that you contrive is of your own imagination.

Comment: @MatsPetersson No, I am not asking which is better.  How you arrived at that conclusion is beyond my comprehension.  I suggest you not try to read into the question but understand (if you did read the question) that I am asking how to convert an if-else to a ternary conditional statement.

Comment: So, you already have a perfectly good if-else statmenet, and you want to destroy it? Good luck!

Comment: @MatsPetersson Ternary operator with no more than one level of nesting is highly readable.  With the answer provided that currently has 3 votes and was elected, I have no problem using a ternary operator provided the expressions after `?` are short which, in my case, just happen to be quite terse.  Thus, readability is not affected.  However, if I were interested in nesting beyond one level or using highly verbose expressions, then I would conclude an `if-else` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't compare booleans to true and false. There's no point because they're true or false already! Just write

```
if (x)
{
    // do this on behalf of x
    // do this on behalf of x
    // do this on behalf of x
}
```

Your second example doesn't compile because you use `{` and `}`. But this might

```
x ? ( /*do a*/, /*do b*/, /*do c*/ ) : y ? ... ;
```

but it does depend on what `/*do a*/` etc are.

Comment: Good point and thank you regarding booleans but that was just for illustration purposes as I was trying to make a meaningful example.  Now I will try your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using comma operator to string different expressions together is within the rules of the language, but it makes the code harder to read (because you have to spot the comma, which isn't always easy, especially if the expression isn't really simple.

The other factor is of course that you can ONLY do this for `if (x) ... else if(y) ...` type conditionals state.

Sometimes, it seems like people prefer "short code" from "readable code", which is of course great if you are in a competition of "who can write this in the fewest lines", but for everything else, particularly code that "on show" or shared with colleagues that also need to understand it - once a software project gets sufficiently large, it usually becomes hard to understand how the code works WITHOUT obfuscation that makes the code harder to read. I don't really see any benefit in using conditional statements in the way your second example described. It is possible that the example is bad, but generally, I'd say "don't do that".

Comment: I should have noted that the expressions I use are highly terse and very simple.

Comment: Show a REAL sample of the actual code (in your question, as comments with code are rubbish on SO).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it works (with C++11). I have not tried a solution but following [Herb Sutters way](http://herbsutter.com/2013/04/05/complex-initialization-for-a-const-variable/) you can use ether a function call or a lambda which is immediately executed:

```
cond ? 
  [&]{
    int i = some_default_value;
    if(someConditionIstrue)
    {
        Do some operations ancalculate the value of i;
        i = some calculated value;
    }
    return i;
} ()  
  : 
somefun() ;
```

I have not tried to compile it but here you have an result whih is either computed with an lambda or an normal function.